# Why do no marketing standards apply to coconuts?

Tags: england-and-wales, food

According to a [recent answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/92596/35069) coconuts are subject to neither the specific marketing standard, nor the general marketing standard. By reason of  which legal provision is this so?

Answer (score 0):

The linked answer gives the reason: the law on food labels doesn’t require it.

Asking why the politicians drafted the law that way is off-topic on this site.

Comment: No, it’s more asking under which law is or not required? It’s petty obvious that Parliament passed some law or other that either didn’t require it or that allowed it to not be required, and the question isn’t why they did so, but rather which law is the situation such because of?

Comment: This is a valid comment, but shouldn't have been posted as an answer.